# Changing the X and Y position of the input's cursor/pointer

Tags: python-3.x, input, coordinates, cursor-position, colorama

So, I have this code here:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored
init()

print(Fore.RED + "Command >> ")  ## Red-colored print statement
print(Style.RESET_ALL)   ## Reseting the colors back to default (so the input won't be red aswell)
print("\033[%d;%dH" % (1, 1))   ## Changing X and Y pos
inp = input()  ## Getting Input
```

And as you can see, I'm trying to `print` a red-colored "Command >>" and change the `input`'s coordinates to be in front of the printed statement. But, it didn't work and the `input` always stay under the printed statement. I chose `Colorama` module because, it helps printing with colors etc...

If anyone didn't understand or wants an elaboration of the above question, I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer! here it is if someone is curious:

```
import sys
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
init()

def printPos(x, y, text_to_print):   #Function that let us print in desired Position
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b[%d;%df%s" % (x, y, text_to_print))
    sys.stdout.flush()

print(Fore.RED + "Command >>")   #Red-colored print statement
printPos(1, 11, " ")   #Changing pos to 1, 11
inp = input()    #Getting the input
```